# how to group by a user and show their following in python

Tags: python

The below text is a sample from a raw data text file to perform analysis.
The format of raw data is: user1 follows user2 user3 user4. For example, the first line means: tony follows tom and frank. 
Thus, tony are the followers for tom and frank.

```
tony tom frank  (it means tony follows tom and frank)
tom             (it means tom follows no one)
tom tony jordan (it means tom follows tony and jordan)
frank tom tony  (it means frank follows tom and tony)
jordan frank    (it means jordan follows frank)
tom frank       (it means tom follows frank)


Thus
1. tom's followers are tony and frank
2. tony's followers are tom and frank
3. frank's followers are tony and jordan and tom
4. jordan's followers is just tom.
```

I would like to compute a table to analyse who is the have most followers.
I want to get the output like: user1 have followers: user2, user3, user4
The code I tried didn't give me a correct one. Anyone can help?

I've tried as below:

```
**with open("sample.txt", 'r') as fhand:
    aCompleteUserDict = {}
    aCompleteUserList = []

    for line in fhand:
        allUsers = line.split()  # This part is to convert each line in the file into a list
        for aUser in allUsers[0:]:
            aCompleteUserDict[aUser] = allUsers[1:]  
            #fan = allUsers[0]

    print(aCompleteUserDict)**




***The actual output for my try is:***
{'tony': ['tom', 'tony'], 'tom': ['frank'], 'frank': ['frank'], 'jordan': ['frank']}


***My expected output format is:***

{'tony': ['tom', 'frank'], 'tom': ['frank', 'tony']], 'frank': ['tony', 'jordan', 'tom'], 'jordan': ['tom']}
```

Comment: I think you need to explain more clearly why your input gives this output: `'tom': ['frank', ['tony']]`. Why is Tony in a nested list?

Comment: @BoarGules Hello! in `tony tom frank` and `frank tom tony` part, for the first part means `tony follows tom and frank`. The second part means `frank follows tom and tony`. So, tom have followers: `frank and tony`.

Comment: Then why doesn't `tom tony jordan` give `'jordan': ['tom', ['tony']]`? And what does the nesting mean, anyway? I know it's so obvious to you that it needs only an example to explain it. But not to me.

Comment: @BoarGules I have updated the post anyway.

Comment: @BoarGules it was just a typo! Sorry

Comment: I had previously misinterpreted your question. Now, I have updated my answer and it matches the output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that can be easily adapted to reading from a file.

```
str_1 = 'tony tom frank'
str_2 = 'tom'        
str_3 = 'tom tony jordan'
str_4 = 'frank tom tony'
str_5 = 'jordan frank'
str_6 = 'tom frank'


str_list = [str_1, str_2, str_3, str_4, str_5, str_6]


aCompleteUserDict = {}

for string in str_list:
    allUsers = string.split()
    follower, followed = allUsers[0], allUsers[1:]
    for foll in followed:
        if foll not in aCompleteUserDict.keys():
            aCompleteUserDict[foll] = [follower]
        else:
            aCompleteUserDict[foll].append(follower)

print(aCompleteUserDict)

{'tom': ['tony', 'frank'], 'frank': ['tony', 'jordan', 'tom'], 'tony': ['tom', 'frank'], 'jordan': ['tom']}
```

Comment: You are very welcome! I would recommend leaving a comment if the answer you get is not what you expect, so that mistakes can be rectified.